# XSL Stylesheet - Image resize

Tags: xml, xslt, rss

I want to resize images from an RSS feed (XML file) that don't have a set size attribute.

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
<img src="https://s.aolcdn.com/dims-shared/dims3/GLOB/crop/5270x3360+0+0/resize/1600x1020!/format/jpg/quality/85/http://hss-prod.hss.aol.com/hss/storage/midas/bd48965fe1e1f68f097f1ffacf4eae4f/202451485/482332148.jpg" />Google is no stranger to using machine learning to improve its products -- or save manatees. To that end, the internet juggernaut has announced that its algorithms are capable of successfully pulling business names and phone numbers from Street View...
]]>
</description>
```

My XSL file until now:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="TITLE"/>
<xsl:template match="rss">
  <div style="padding:0; font-size:1em;">

     <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name()='item'][position() &lt; 6]">
        <a href="{link}" target="_new"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></a>, 

        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="description"/><br/>

        <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="pubDate"/><br/>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="description"><xsl:value-of select="."/><br/></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your stated desire of resizing images is not addressed anywhere in your code, which is a bit confusing.  None of your XSL code targets the `img` element in your sample input XML.

Comment: I know something like this:

 <xsl:param name="pmaxSize" select="100"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@orginalwidth">
  <xsl:attribute name="size">
   <xsl:value-of select=".*not(. > $pmaxSize) + $pmaxSize*(. > $pmaxSize)"/>
   <xsl:text>px</xsl:text>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

would work... but it doesn't without an size element in the XML file

Comment: That snippet in your comment will only apply if the input XML includes an attribute with the name `originalWidth`.  Since your sample input XML has no such attribute, that XSL code won't ever be called.  I suggest you read up on how template matching works.  I also suggest that you read up on the RSS specification -- neither spec [version 1.0](http://web.resource.org/rss/1.0/spec) nor [version 2.0](https://cyber.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html) include any `<img>` tag, only `<image>`, and neither includes any `originalWidth` attribute anywhere.  Is your input XML from a non-compliant version of RSS?